# Not able to scroll on custom scrollbar using Selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selenium

We are using custom scrollbar(`mcustomscrollbar`) for our website, but I am not able to scroll through custom scroll bar using `selenium`. Tried:

`injecting javascript ( Eg: ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", el) ).`

But no use,  it doesn't work.

Finally I found a solution using injecting jquery:

```
jQuery('.mCustomScrollbar').mCustomScrollbar('scrollTo',$('#xyz'))
```

Now I need to scroll using a particular webelement instead of id attribute. Is there a way for that using any kind of technique?

Reference: 
Check this image: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1y-4W_7TTOXU1lBdEt6WkNrZFE/view?usp=sharing

[SignUp for more information here](https://www.vtiger.com/begin-free-trial/)

Comment: I don't think jquery identifies the elements the way selenium does. You can use other ways like class or attribute instead of id to get the element to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

you added `css`

```
 style="display: table-cell; height: 100vh; vertical-align: middle; max-width: 100vw;overflow: scroll;position: fixed;margin-left: -306px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured out how to do this with just Javascript, but I do the following to scroll my mcustomscrollbar:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.class")));
```

.. where 'driver' is the Webdriver instance.  The div.class can be any CSS element.

I got to this page by trying to see if anyone has had issues with mcustomscrollbar sometimes scrolling back to the top of the page, instead of staying put.  For me right now, I have to scroll down for each form input on the bottom of the page, which is works only most of the time.  You see anything like that Suresh?

EDIT: Also found [this page](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) that provided me with this scroll command that's working for me.

```
    ((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("$('.mCustomScrollbar#content').mCustomScrollbar('scrollTo',document.querySelector(\"div.class button.class\"))");
```

You can use any CSS selector in the querySelector.